# Require config file in class

Tags: php, require

I want to use the variables that has been declared in a config.php file in a class for testing. I am not sure if this is the right way like I have done it.

I have a configuration file, config.php:

```
class Config {

    public $hosts = array(
        'a' => '192.168.1.10'
        'b' => '192.168.1.11',
    );

    public $ports = array(
        'a' => 22,
        'b' => 22,
    );
}
```

This variables I want to include in a file called Tests.php:

```
require_once 'config.php';

    class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
        protected $hosts;
        protected $ports;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $config = new Config();
            $this->hosts = $config->hosts;
            $this->portsSsh = $config->ports;
        }


        public function testConnect()
        {
            $session = $this->connect($this->hosts['a'], $this->ports['a']);
            $this->closeConnection($session);
        }
    ...
    }
```

Is it right doing it like this? 
I have the impression it is too complicated. I have to make a class for the config.php file and in the test class I have to do like a mapping $this->hosts = $config->hosts.

Isn't there a simpler way? I don't want to use globals.

Comment: Why not a real config file (config.ini) that you parse using the parse_ini_file PHP function ?

Comment: In and of itself, the only direct issue here is that your `Config`-related code should be in a `setUp` method, rather than the constructor. But what worries me more is the way you've written your `Config` class. Having your config hard-coded in PHP is considered to be rather unsafe, and can make your code hard to use in a sizeable project. Please consider posting some of your code [on codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get more details on the matter, and some advice on how to better tackle the issue

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: Thank you for your answer and the recommendation. I did it.

Answer (score 0):

That's completely fine!

PhpUnit has a method called setUp, that's used for this type of cases.
Its called before every test method is run.

There's also tearDown() just in case.

Comment: You mean using the setUp() method instead of the constructor?

Comment: Yes! That way if you need those settings in other files, you could move it to a parent class.